# Compound interest rate

Tags: compound-interest

Given annual interest rate r_ann and n compounds per year, why do we use the formula

`(1+r_ann/n)^tn`

rather than `(1+r)^tn` given `r = (1+r_ann)^(1/n) - 1`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your rate `r_ann` in `(1+r_ann/n)^tn` is a *nominal* rate compounded over a specific period, which means for example, a monthly rate has been simply multiplied by 12 to produce a "*nominal annual rate compounded monthly*", in order to make the calculation of the monthly rate easier, (just divide by 12).

The alternative is to use an *effective* annual rate, which indeed is the legal requirement in the EU when quoting an annual percentage rate (APR).

Converting between Nominal and Effective APR is described here:-

Wikipedia: [Effective interest rate - Calculation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation)

For example, 10% Nominal APR compounded monthly is 10.4713% Effective APR

```
(1 + 0.10/12)^12 - 1 = 0.104713
```

and 10% Effective APR is 9.56897% Nominal APR compounded monthly

```
((0.10 + 1)^(1/12) - 1)*12 = 0.0956897
```

Finally, reference 3 on the Wikipedia [APR page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annual_percentage_rate#References) is quite illuminating:-

- Source: webpage: [US-Federal-Reserve-R1314](https://www.federalreserve.gov/SECRS/2008/July/20080708/R-1314/R-1314_10005_1.pdf)

> The "Truth in Lending Act" passed in 1968 did not incorporate the
>   mathematically-true annual percentage rate, because the true
>   calculation used compounding (sometime fraction compounding), which
>   was not readily available. The result on expression of the APR on
>   credit cards uses a Nominal (simple interest) method ... which can far
>   from the truth. The Truth in Lending Act should be changed to the
>   mathematically-true (EFFECTIVE) APR from the untrue (NOMINAL) APR,
>   merely by changing the word in act from "multiplied by" to "compounded
>   for".

"*the true calculation used compounding ... which was not readily available.*" - i.e. difficult to calculate, especially in 1968.