# Why does APR not include compounding?

Tags: apr

As I understand it the Annual Percentage Rate (APR) formula does not take compounding into account. It is, in effect, a nominal rate.

Why is this? I thought that APR was designed to allow consumers to compare products from different financial institutions as best as is possible. How does excluding compounding help this aim?

Comment: You may be thinking of APY (annual percentage *yield*), which is what allows you to compare offerings with different rates, terms, and fees.

Comment: APR (in the US) is an anachronism, left over from the days before computers.  See https://money.stackexchange.com/a/124507/11768 : "*The "Truth in Lending Act" passed in 1968 did not incorporate the mathematically-true annual percentage rate, because the true calculation used compounding (sometime fraction compounding), which was not readily available.*" i.e. difficult to calculate without a pocket calculator.